# How to prevent displaying the home page after logging out

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

Here is my **routes.php**

```
<?php
#HomePage
Route::get('/', 'LoginController@home');
Route::post('login', 'LoginController@Login');
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
Route::get('home', 'HomeController@HomeLayout');
Route::get('logout', 'LoginController@Logout');
});
```

In the logout i have

```
   public function Logout()
    {
        Session::flush();
        return Redirect::to('');
    }
```

Once i do logout i am succesfully redirected to `''` page i.e., **localhost/home** as i have this in my logincontroller

```
public function home()
{
    return View::make('login/home');
}
```

My Problem is once i press the logout and i press the back button i can able to see the localhost/home though i have used it inside the `Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()`

I also configured the **filters.php**

```
Route::filter('guest', function()
{
    if (Auth::check()) return Redirect::to('/')->with('Message', 'Please Login to get Access');
});
```

and

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest())
    {
        if (Request::ajax())
        {
            return Response::make('Unauthorized', 401);
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::guest('')->with('Message', 'Please Login to get Access');
        }
    }
});
```

**Note :** Once i refresh it directs to logout , but i don't even want to display the home even before they do refresh

**How can i prevent displaying the home screen after pressing back button from browser once they logged out ?**

Answer (score 1):

```
App::after(function($request, $response)
{
    $response->headers->set('Cache-Control','nocache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
    $response->headers->set('Pragma','no-cache');
    $response->headers->set('Expires','Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT');
});
```

add these lines in `routes.php` and check.

this will clear the `cache`

Comment: Whilst this answer is correct - just remember that you are preventing the browser from caching - so you are trading off performance for this.